# Google Chrome won't install on 17.04

Tags: google-chrome, 17.04

I had to remove Chrome to have enough space to upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04.  I downloaded the latest version from Google.  But when it opens in the Ubuntu Software Manager, and I click on "Install", nothing happens.

Comment: A fix has been released https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1672424

Comment: You'd be better off installing chromium instead :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it doesn't actually contain a question and because bug reports are off topic. On top of that this bug was fixed in "proposed" which is going to make this thread moot soon enough.

Answer (score 9):

Gdebi worked for me

Gdebi is a `.deb` package installer, that serves as an alternative to Software Center for this specific task I.e, installing `.deb` files.

All you need to do is install it and open your `.deb` files through it

To install gdebi copy and paste the command below in your terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

For future use make sure to set it as default until an update fixes the issue with Software Center.

[Fix has been released for this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1672424)

Comment: I'll report it and initiate the fix process for the Software Center.

Comment: Solution worked for me too, Xubuntu 17.04 desktop amd64.

Comment: Why not use `dpkg`?

Comment: fix released https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1672424

Comment: This worked for me: ole@mkiv:~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: Software center still does not work even after full 17.04 update

Answer (score 4):

First that you need to setup the key and repository.

Setup key with:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Setup repository with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sou
```

[3rd Party Repository: Google Chrome](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome)

Then use apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Xubuntu 17.04: 
    
    stephen@Aspire-V3:~$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
    <--snipped-->
    Package 'google-chrome-stable' has no installation candidate

Comment: [3rd Party Repository: Google Chrome](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome) try the commands here

Comment: Consider [edit]ing improvements into your answer as comments can be deleted for various reasons (and not everyone reads them). Improving the quality of your answer may stop it from showing up in the low quality answer queue.

Answer (score 4):

There might be some dependency problem. So, what you could do is:

1. Download chrome `.deb` file from official chrome site
2. Open terminal in that download folder
3. in terminal run these commands:

commands

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

So, the first command will try to install the package. And if there is any dependency problem, then it will fail.

Second command will force apt to automatically install all missing/required dependencies, and the bet part is you don't even need to specify anything, apt will automatically get those.

In 3rd step when you try to install chrome again, now it will be installed successfully.

You can follow these steps for all deb files.

Comment: Apt has been improved so that it can handle `.deb` files. Try `sudo apt install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`, and it will handle any dependency problems.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex thanks for informing, i didn't knew about that.

Comment: I cannot find any information about option `-f` by `man`

Comment: @yode "apt" is a high level implementation of "package management system", whereas "apt-get" is low-level implementation. You should do `man apt-get`, and then you will see "-f" means `--fix-broken`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command line utility `dpkg` to install .deb files.

```
sudo dpkg -i <deb file path>
```

Comment: It's better to use `sudo apt install <.deb file>` these days, since that will install the `.deb` file and handle dependencies as well. From past experience, `dpkg` will stop unsuccessfully halfway through installing Chrome and tell you to run `apt install -f`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Never knew about installing .deb packages from apt (thanks for sharing), this would probably be the best way to install it. (If the apt command works in the same way with autoremove that makes uninstalling the package with dependencies a lot easier also.)