# ubuntu 17.04 broken AMDGPU-PRO support

Tags: amd-graphics, 17.04, amdgpu

(This is a fresh install of Ubuntu UEFI (gpt) 17.04 64bit)

If there is a way to install the AMDGPU PRO driver? I would like to know how to proceed.

- AMDGPU-PRO

from their website running:

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
```

gives me:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching amdgpu-pro
```

Comment: So, basically, everything from the repositories works, and everything from outside may or may not. Given 17.04 is new, It might take third party vendors to catch up. You need to post more specific questions about each problem, with logs, errors, etc. As is, the question is too vague and too broad.

Comment: Also, comment on whether this is a fresh install or an upgrade.  I suspect it is the former but please specify.

Comment: Package skype is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'skype' has no installation candidate

-----------------------------------------------
this is basically the message i get in terminal after a sudo apt install of each of these. nothing too interesting.

Comment: also oracle-java, obs and grub-customiser are all from outside repos so that assumption is false

Comment: To install chrome check the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905780/google-chrome-wont-install-on-17-04/905787#905787)

Comment: that answer was quite borked but upon working around it's borks I managed to  make it work. thanks!

Comment: Some issues and solutions here: Trying AMDGPU-PRO 17.10 On Ubuntu 17.04 (does not work directly)
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMDGPU-PRO-Ubuntu-17.04 and:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard that the problem stays with the updated Ubuntu Store. Did you try **Gdebi package Manager** for .deb applications like Chrome ? It worked me while I was using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.

Comment: yes this works for chrome, virtualbox, discord, skype and atom thanks!