# Software Install not working (GNOME Software)

Tags: gnome, software-installation, software-center, 17.04

I've just made a fresh install of Linux **Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 Zesty Zapus** on my laptop, but as I am trying to install my first application — `opera-stable_45.0.2552.635_amd64.deb` — the installer becomes "unresponsive".

When I right-click the `.deb` package and choose `Open with Software Install` from the menu, I am taken correctly to `GNOME Software` where `opera-stable` is displayed before my eyes. When I click the button `Install` however, nothing happens. The installer does not freeze or become unresponsive in a sense that I would have to kill it; it's just that nothing happens when I push the `Install` button.

Another observation I made — possibly irrelevant though — is that when I go to `Software & Updates > Other software` and try to enable `Canonical Partners` by ticking the small box in front of it, nothing happens either. Well, all the menus and buttons **do** turn gray, but clicking any point on the screen turns them "active" again.

Any ideas what this all might be about? Moreover, any ideas for troubleshooting / making things right again?

Thanks for helping a newbie!

**NOTE**: I am not sure if this is related, but by glancing through the list of installed applications in `GNOME Software`, I noticed that some applications appear twice in the list. These applications are: `GNOME Control Center`, `Photos`, and `Software & Updates`. Perhaps the apparent double-installation of the last one can somehow interrupt the normal installation process? Just a thought...

Answer (score 2):

[image: opera ubuntu 17]

Like this ? :)

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gdebi
```

right click on the `.deb` select "Properties" go into the "Open with" tab select gdebi and set as default keep it this way untill ubuntu fixes software center for 17.04 or heck forever. Honestly I've [recently](https://askubuntu.com/a/905901/307184) discovered this tool and can't believe I've been missing this all my life!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that out! Meanwhile, I reported the issue as a possible bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1690542)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get `Software Install` of `GNOME Store` working by enabling the `Pre-released updates (zesty-proposed)` from `Software & Updates > Developer Options`.

As @tatsu suggested above, installing `gdebi` might be another way to fix the problem, but this method is to answer the specific problem in question.

Cheers!

Comment: Not too fast. After enabling `Pre-released updates (zesty-proposed)`, I've already filed three (automatic, thank God) bug reports, and the `opera-stable` installation process always gets stuck to 51%. @tatsu, I think I might go your way :-)

Comment: yeah I'd though as much ;)